# Spline in 3 Dimensions for Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, curve-fitting, spline

I'm looking for a function which mimics MATLAB's [`cscvn` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cscvn.html) in their Curve Fitting Toolbox, suitable for points in 3D space. The closest function I've found has been [scipy.interpolate.splprep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html), which is capable of computing 3 dimensions but loses its accuracy with fewer data points. If smoothness is reduced to a point of fitting the points, the curve has kinks.

I have a discrete dataset made up of physical points (elevation data) that I'm looking to model, so the spline must pass through those points. There is a finite number of points at varying chord lengths from one another.

Here's a sample of the quick test function I've written to test Python splines. Unfortunately, I can't share my MATLAB code, but the `cscvn` function splines smoothly and passes through all data points.

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev, interp2d

x = np.linspace(0, 10, num = 20)   #list of known x coordinates
y = 2*x   #list of known y coordinates
z = x*x   #list of known z coordinates
## Note: You must have more points than degree of the spline. if k = 3, must have 4 points min.

print([x,y,z])

tck, u = splprep([x,y,z], s = 26)  # Generate function out of provided points, default k = 3
newPoints = splev(u, tck)          # Creating spline points
print(newPoints)

ax = plt.axes(projection = "3d")
ax.plot3D(x, y, z, 'go')     # Green is the actual 3D function
ax.plot3D(newPoints[:][0], newPoints[:][1], newPoints[:][2], 'r-')   # Red is the spline
plt.show()
```

Here is an example of many points creating a smooth curve (red), but the line doesn't align with the physical data points (green).

[image: Lots of Points, Spline Misses]

Here is an example of kinks in the spline (red) created by too few data points (green). This is more akin to what my dataset looks like.

[image: Too few points, Spline Kinks]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you done so far? Could you share your code?

Comment: I added some additional detail

Comment: @SardarUsama Code is shared in text form

Answer (score -1):

Change your U for:

unew = np.arange(0, 1.00, 0.005)